# Configure EXIM to keep copy of incoming emails and relay to same domain on remote server

Tags: exim

I am trying to figure out how configure EXIM to achieve the following.

Incoming emails to be saved on the users' mailboxes and be relayed on remote server that has the same accounts.

There are two mail servers, 1.2.3.4 on which MX records of *example.com* point to, and 5.6.7.8 which has the same domain.

I have inserted the following on exim conf of 1.2.3.4

```
redir:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = example.com
  transport = remote_smtp
  route_list = * 5.6.7.8
```

but this just relays the emails to the account *test@example.com* on server 5.6.7.8 without keeping a copy on the existing local mailbox *test@example.com*.

Any ideas on how to make exim keep a copy on the first mail box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That router should be placed before all other routers. It should be ended with the `unseen` verb:

```
redir:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = example.com
  transport = remote_smtp
  route_list = * 5.6.7.8
  unseen
```

Comment: Thanks for the lightning fast response. Adding the unseen did the trick!